# best way to get unique values of 2 arrays which different structure?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays like this:

```
blockedUsers = ['u1', 'u2', 'u3']
videoList = [
    {
        id: 1,
        mp4URL: '...mp4',
        user: {
            id: 'u1',
            name: 'User 1'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        mp4URL: '...mp4',
        user: {
            id: 'u2',
            name: 'User 1'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        mp4URL: '...mp4',
        user: {
            id: 'u5',
            name: 'User 1'
        }
    }
]
```

I want to remove blocked users from video array. At final I will get array has 1 video from u5. How to do that?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter out elements where user id is not included in blocked users.

```
videoList.filter(v => !blockedUsers.includes(v.user.id))
```

Comment: Thank you alot, I still finding a way using for loop with lot of code inside. You just make it with 1 line :o

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of methods for the same. Please find `Array.filter` implementation of the same.

```js
const blockedUsers = ['u1', 'u2', 'u3']
const videoList = [
  { id: 1, mp4URL: '...mp4', user: { id: 'u1', name: 'User 1' } },
  { id: 2, mp4URL: '...mp4', user: { id: 'u2', name: 'User 1' } },
  { id: 3, mp4URL: '...mp4', user: { id: 'u5', name: 'User 1' } }
];
const output = videoList.filter((node) => blockedUsers.indexOf(node.user.id) === -1);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the list by using the [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method.

```js
const
  blockedUsers = ['u1', 'u2', 'u3'],
  videoList = [
    { id: 1, mp4URL: '...mp4', user: { id: 'u1', name: 'User 1' } },
    { id: 2, mp4URL: '...mp4', user: { id: 'u2', name: 'User 1' } },
    { id: 3, mp4URL: '...mp4', user: { id: 'u5', name: 'User 1' } }
  ],
  allowedVideos = videoList.filter(({ user: { id } }) => !blockedUsers.includes(id));

console.log(allowedVideos);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways

First way, you could filter the `videoList` and iterate to check if the user is in the blocked list. We could do this with `.includes` for `blockedUsers`, but this way will result in the complexity of `O(n*m)`, given that n is the length of `blockedUsers` and m is the length of `videoList`

Second way, you could first turn the `blockedUsers` into a hash table using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). This will reduce the query time complexity for `blockedUsers` from `O(n)` to `O(1)`. In this way, the overall time complexity would be `O(n + m)`, which is better than the first way

```js
const blockedUsers = ["u1", "u2", "u3"]
const videoList = [ { id: 1, mp4URL: "...mp4", user: { id: "u1", name: "User 1", }, }, { id: 2, mp4URL: "...mp4", user: { id: "u2", name: "User 1", }, }, { id: 3, mp4URL: "...mp4", user: { id: "u5", name: "User 1", }, }, ]

const blockedUsersHashTable = new Set(blockedUsers)

const res = videoList.filter(
  ({ user: { id } }) => !blockedUsersHashTable.has(id)
)

console.log(res)
```

If time complexity is not your concern, just go with the first way.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const blockedUsers = ['u1', 'u2', 'u3'];
const videoList = [
    {
        id: 1,
        mp4URL: '...mp4',
        user: {
            id: 'u1',
            name: 'User 1'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        mp4URL: '...mp4',
        user: {
            id: 'u2',
            name: 'User 1'
        }
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        mp4URL: '...mp4',
        user: {
            id: 'u5',
            name: 'User 1'
        }
    }
];

const target = videoList.filter(v => !blockedUsers.includes(v.user.id));

console.log(target);
```